# What if we used massive voltages to create a Lichtenberg figure in acrylic?

Tags: electricity, voltage, dielectric, particle-accelerators

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichtenberg_figure

I cannot find anywhere online what the result would be if I used, for example, 1GeV compared to the 10-20MeV which are usually used. This is all theoretical, and clearly, I don't have access to such a high-voltage appliance, I'm just curious.

Is it possible to predict, or would this just have to be experimented with? I assume it would melt the polymer due to Ohmic heating, or perhaps even cause an explosion due to the rapid expansion of gas within the channels of the figure.

Please let me know your thoughts.

[image: A figure in PMMA (acrylic)]

Comment: Current capacity is also an issue. One electron at 1GeV doesn't do much...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few problems with using a 1-GeV beam.

1. The beam needs to stop inside the acrylic so charge can build up before discharging. Since the article says that 25-MeV beams easily penetrate the acrylic, a 1-GeV beam would cause a significant amount of electrons to pass all the way through and out the other side. It would actually take longer to create the figure.
2. As electrons slow down in the acrylic, they release radiation (mostly X-rays) called [Bremsstrahlung radiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung). Higher energy beams create more intense raduation. The intensity goes up with the cube of the beam energy, so immense amounts of shielding would be required to protect any nearby humans.
3. You are right to be concerned with heating the insulator. I've seen a misdirected 2-MeV proton beam burn a hole through a structure made of stainless steel and copper. Granted, that was a 10-mA beam, which is a large current for most accelerators.
4. Creating a 1-GeV beam takes a very large accelerator. The [LCLS-II](https://lcls.slac.stanford.edu/lcls-ii) accelerator at Stanford University produces a 4-GeV beam with a 2-mile long accelerator.

[image: Aerial view of the LCLS-II facility at SLAC]

These are hard challenges, but that's why we physicists hire engineers: so we don't have to deal with the annoying details of reality.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and useful reply - Could I contact you directly about this somehow?

Comment: @m1zzzz We can chat here.

Comment: Ok no worries. Say I put 1 GeV with appropriate safety measures etc., how slowly would the streamers form in the polymer compared to with a 'lower' voltage? Also, would an electromagnetic/magnetic field interact with the electrons and thus the randomness of the streamers?

Comment: @m1zzzz I actually have no idea. I would imagine that any polymer substance would not survive any length of time before it completely melted or had a hole tunneled through it. For comparison, the beam dumps at the end of GeV-energy accelerators that catch the unused part of the beam are massive structures involving literal tons of metal (aluminum, steel, tungsten, and lead) to absorb the beam and radiation. Even then, the beam has to be constantly steered so that no one spot on the shielding is continuously hit or else it would start to melt.